# add radio buttons and lables to d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add radio buttons to an area with axis and shapes like this:

```
var triangleFunctions = ['Perpendicular Bisector', 'Median', 'Altitude'],
    selected = 0;

var form = svg.append('form');

var labelEnter = form.selectAll('span')
                     .data(triangleFunctions)
                     .enter().append('span');

labelEnter.append('input').attr({
  type: 'radio',
  class: 'shape',
  name: 'mode',
  value: function(d, i) {return i;}
});

labelEnter.append("label").text(function(d) {return d;});
```

You can see a jsbin of the code [here](http://jsbin.com/ziganuw/1/edit?js,output).

The labels and inputs are not appearing.

Comment: You can't append non-SVG elements to an SVG container.  You can use the `body` like `var form = d3.select("body").append('form');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [foreignObject](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#EmbeddingForeignObjects) (but be aware that it does not work in IE):

```
var form = svg.append("foreignObject").attr("width", "400")
    .attr("height", "50").append("xhtml:body").append('form');
```

Note that `body` tag is required, and it also has to contain `xhtml:` part.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/mafikorezo/edit?js,output

Comment: Are there any sort of svg controls or how is there anything cross platform that I could have used to have a similar effect that will work cross platform?

Comment: @dagda1, don't use `foreignObject`, if you want it "on" the `svg` just add it to the body and position it properly.  Example [here](http://jsbin.com/toyivowece/1/edit?js,output).

Comment: Better than “xhtml:body” would be “xhtml:html” so that if you ever need to append something to the body of the page (e.g., using jQuery), there’s only one of them.